# How can I legally sell this property abroad?

Tags: united-kingdom, real-estate, international-transfer, capital-gain, bangladesh

I have a property in Bangladesh worth around £500k. I built this property legally many years ago however I moved to the UK around 18 years ago.

When I moved, I had changed my name legally meaning that the property is still in my Bengali name.

How do I sell this property legally and bring the money to the UK?

Comment: Do you have records showing your ownership and also showing your legal name change? This feels off-topic for this site, but if you have paperwork to show those two things then not sure why there'd be an issue.

Comment: I believe Bangladesh is one of the countries which has fairly draconian foreign exchange controls, so getting your money in GBP may require some effort.

Answer (score 2):

> How do I sell this property legally

If you have changed the name legally; there is no issue. You can submit the required documentation and sell the property in Bangladesh.

> bring the money to the UK?

As per Bangladesh [Foreign Exchange Regulation Act](http://bdlaws.minlaw.gov.bd/print_sections_all.php?id=218); there are limitations to transfer of funds outside of Bangladesh. Read the [detail guideline, section 11](https://www.bb.org.bd/aboutus/regulationguideline/foreignexchange/fegv1cont.php) Private Remittance maybe relevant. A professional help is advised as there would be paperwork required.